# Find $m_{0,3}$, $m_{1,3}$, $m_{2,3}$

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains

Find $m_{0,3}$, $m_{1,3}$, and $m_{2,3}$ if $$ P=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0.7 & 0 & 0.3 & 0\\
        0.5 & 0 & 0.5 & 0\\
        0 & 0.4 & 0 & 0.6\\
        0 & 0.2&0&0.8\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
Would state 0 $\rightarrow$ $m_{1,0}$ = 1 + $P_{11}$$m_{1,0}$ + $P_{12}$$m_{2,0}$ + $P_{13}$$m_{3,0}$
and $m_{2,0}$ = 1 + $P_{21}$$m_{1,0}$ + $P_{22}$$m_{2,0}$ + $P_{23}$$m_{3,0}$
and $m_{3,0}$ = 1 + $P_{31}$$m_{1,0}$ + $P_{32}$$m_{2,0}$ + $P_{33}$$m_{3,0}$ 
and so on for state 1,2, and 3? I am a little confused on how to set up the equations to solve for mean first passage times.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M_3 = \inf \{ n \ge 0 \mid X_n=3 \}$. We want to find $\mathbb{E}_i[M_3] := \mathbb{E}[M_3 \mid X_0 = i]$ for $i=0,1,2,3$.

Trivially $\mathbb{E}_3[M_3] =0$. From first step conditioning, 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}_0[M_3] &=  \frac{7}{10} \left( 1 + \mathbb{E}_0[M_3] \right) + \frac{3}{10} \left( 1 + \mathbb{E}_2[M_3] \right) = 1 + \frac{7}{10}  \mathbb{E}_0[M_3] + \frac{3}{10} \mathbb{E}_2[M_3]  \\[5pt]
\mathbb{E}_1[M_3] &= \frac{1}{2} \left( 1 + \mathbb{E}_0[M_3] \right) + \frac{1}{2} \left( 1 + \mathbb{E}_2[M_3] \right) = 1 +\frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}_0[M_3]+ \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}_2[M_3] \\[5pt]
\mathbb{E}_2[M_3] &= \frac{2}{5} \left( 1 + \mathbb{E}_1[M_3] \right) + \frac{3}{5} \left( 1  \right) = 1 + \frac{2}{5} \mathbb{E}_1[M_3]  \\
\end{align*}

Solving gives $\frac{61}{9}, \frac{55}{9},\frac{31}{9}$ for $\mathbb{E}_0[M_3], \mathbb{E}_1[M_3], \mathbb{E}_2[M_3]$, respectively.